# Compare two group results

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following 2 dataframe:

```
DF1:
   DATE           ID_1 ID_2 RESULT
0  2014-06-16     1    a    RED
1  2014-07-01     1    a    WHITE
2  2014-08-16     2    c    BLUE
3  2015-08-16     3    a    RED


DF2
   DATE           ID_1 ID_2 RESULT
0  2014-06-16     1    z    WHITE
1  2014-07-01     1    z    WHITE
2  2014-08-16     2    h    BLUE
3  2014-08-16     3    k    RED
```

That you can obtain by running this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["DATE","ID_1", "ID_2", "RESULT" ])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["DATE","ID_1", "ID_2","RESULT"])

df1["DATE"] = ['2014-06-16', '2014-07-01', '2014-08-16', '2015-08-16']
df1['ID_1'] = [1,1,2,3]
df1['ID_2'] = ['a', 'a', 'c', 'a']
df1['RESULT'] = ['RED', 'WHITE', 'BLUE', 'RED']

df2["DATE"] = ['2014-06-16', '2014-07-01', '2014-08-16' ,  '2014-08-16']
df2['ID_1'] = [1,1,2,3]
df2['ID_2'] = ['z', 'z', 'h', 'k']
df2['RESULT'] = ['WHITE', 'WHITE', 'BLUE', 'RED']
```

Now I need to groupby "ID_1" on both and compare if all columns (except ID_2) are equals. Ideally by showing the differences

The result should be like:

```
 DATE           ID_1 ID_2x ID2y  RESULTx RESULTy
 2014-06-16     1    z     a     WHITE   RED
```

I tried by grouping as follow:

```
 grp1 = df1.groupby("ID_1")
 grp2 = df2.groupby("ID_1")

 for (g1,g2) in zip(grp1,grp2):
      g1[1][["DATE", "RESULT"]] != g2[1][["DATE", "RESULT"]]
```

But I think is not efficient. Moreover I get a comparison error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

Any idea about how to proceed ?

Thanks!

Comment: `df1` and `df2` have no `ID_2` values in common. Unless they have the exact same list of unique `ID_2` values, iterating by zipping the groups is a bad idea. And even then, comparing the groups will be tricky as they are likely to be of different length.

Comment: When you say "The result should be like" do you mean that the following code shows one line of the intended result, or the whole intended result?  It's not exactly clear what you want the result of the comparison to be.  Under what conditions should a given row be included in the output?

Comment: You're right there is a typo, just fixed. I mean grouping by ID_1.

Comment: Now with the fixed text should be more clear, apologize for that. The 2 DF are equal except for ID_2 and the first RESULT. So my desired output represents the whole intended result

Comment: Why do you need the groupby?  It seems like you're just comparing rows.

Comment: Also, note the dates in your example differ from the dates in your replication code - which should we follow?

Comment: And how should the result look if, say, the date is different?

Comment: Fixed this too, I modified the code example in the mean time.

Comment: Still, what should the result be if the dates are different?  Should there by a `DATEx` and a `DATEy` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-stating the problem: what you want is to compare two dataframes and find all rows whose values differ (with the exception of a particular column).  Here's one way of doing it:

```
cols = ['DATE', 'ID_1', 'RESULT']
cond = (df1[cols] != df2[cols]).any(axis=1)
new_df = df1[cond].merge(df2[cond], on='ID_1', how='outer', suffixes=('x','y'))
```

(The result differs a little from the one in your answer because I wasn't totally sure about the general behavior you're looking for - see my comments on the answer).